# COUNTIFS function ranging up to today's date

Tags: excel

I have searched through your help but was unable to find the answer that worked with my problem.

I have built an Excel report of numbers that is based on another worksheet almost acting as a database. The user should input all the fields here which will add to the reports. I built a sucessful one using the `COUNTIFS` function in Excel.

However, my boss is asking me to update this so that if he wishes to change the date shown, it will show the numbers up to that date.

So in **column B** dates are added, and I have tried using `$B:$B<=TODAY()` in the criteria section using **column B** as the criteria range, but it only results in a **0**. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Example:

```
=COUNTIFS(Concessions!$B:$B,Concessions!$B:$B=$N$8,Concessions!$G:$G,"Fall 16",Concessions!$H:$H,$A3)
```

where N8 is the current date being searched for.

Would this be easier with a database? Yes, but Excel is what they want to use.

Comment: Could you perhaps show some sample data/how your data is laid out?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use array formula here. `COUNTIFS` takes raw value for equality comparison, or string for more complex condition.

> The criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be counted. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, ">32", B4, "apples", or "32".

```
=COUNTIFS(
    Concessions!$B:$B, "<=" & $N$8,
    Concessions!$G:$G, "Fall 16",
    Concessions!$H:$H, $A3)
```

Comment: It looks like that ampersand was all I was missing. I appreciate you taking the time to answer this.